# Sharepoint 2007 - Content query webpart formmode

Tags: sharepoint

I have got a simple question, but the answer is hard to find. I want to put a contentquery webpart with a custom xslt on my page, but it has to render extra links if the page is opened in edit-mode. So, if (SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Display) : show some extra links near the items in the xslt.

How can I achieve this? I have already overridden the default ContentByQueryWebPart, is that the way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Damn, how easy.


    We are in edit mode!!